# Probability elementary computation help

Tags: probability

I recently started studying the topic of  probability. A question came into my mind , on an exercise. it's about computing the probability of constructing a number of $8$ digits, such that the product of it's digits is even , the easy way to compute this probability is computing the probability of the complementary event of this event , which give the answer $1 -{5^8\over10^8}$  , I tried to compute this probability without using the complementary event , let $A_{i}$ the event: the number contain the digit $i$ , then the probability we looking for is the event 
$\cup_{i=0}^{4} A_{2k}$ , using Poincaré formula it gives : 
$P(\cup_{k=1}^{5} A_{2k-2})=\sum_{k=1}^{5} (-1)^{k-1} \sum_{1\leq i_{1}<..<i_{k}\leq 5} P(A_{i_{1}} \cap ..\cap A_{i_{k}})$  which is 
$P(\cup_{k=1}^{5} A_{2k-2})= \sum_{k=1}^{5} (-1)^{k-1}\binom{5}{k}  \frac{1}{10^{k}}$  but this doesn't give the same answer , can someone help me , thank you .

Comment: I think it should be $1-\frac{5^8}{9\cdot10^7}$, since the first digit shouldn't be a $0$.

Comment: @Nilknarf , the first digit can be $0$ since this number , represent the $8$ last digits of a phone number which conventionnaly start with $06$ thank you

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't call it a "number" but instead a "*string*" or a "*sequence.*"  We do not call $01$ a two digit number, it is merely a one-digit number, however we do call $01$ a two digit string.

Comment: As for your alternate method of calculating, I'm having a hard time parsing your text, what did you find to be the probabilities $Pr(A_0), Pr(A_0\cap A_2),$ and $Pr(A_0\cap A_2\cap A_4)$? for example?  Remember that $Pr(A_0)$ is the probability that it contains at least one $0$ and $Pr(A_0\cap A_2)$ is the probability that it contains at least one $0$ and at least one $2$... these terms seem to be begging for inclusion-exclusion themselves as well

Comment: It should be $Pr(A_0)=1-(\frac{9}{10})^8$ and $Pr(A_0\cap A_2)=1-2(\frac{9}{10})^8+(\frac{8}{10})^8$.  Similarly larger intersections can be calculated, yet I don't see anything resembling these in your calculations.  Instead you have a $\frac{1}{10^k}$, which my best guess is representing the probability that the first $k$ digits in your string are specifically the $k$ indices involved in the intersection appearing in increasing order.  Note again, $Pr(A_0)\neq \frac{1}{10}$, that $A_0$ is the event that at least one $0$ occurs and that occurrence can be anywhere, not just in first position.

Comment: @JMoravitz , thank you yeah you are right , for me I took  $Pr(A_{i})=\frac{1}{10}$ , and since the evenement are independant , $Pr(A_{i_{1}}\cap..\cap A_{i_{k}})=\frac{1}{10^{k}}$

Comment: @oty note that the events **aren't** independent.  For example $Pr(A_0\cap A_1\cap\dots \cap A_9)=Pr(\bigcap\limits_{i=0}^9 A_i)=0\neq \frac{1}{10^{10}}$ since it is impossible for an 8digit string to contain all ten numerals.

Comment: @JMoravitz , wonderfull remark , you are right , my interpretation of $A_{i}$ is then completly work , I should look to another event then

Comment: what if we consider the event  $E_{j}=\{j-th digit~~ is~~even\}$ we have , 5 choices for the $j-th$ one and 10 for the other then , $p(E_{j})=\frac{5.10^{7}}{10^{8}}=\frac{1}{2}$  and the $E_{j}$ are independant

Comment: That would work fine, of course, so you would be looking for $Pr(\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^8 E_j)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^8 \binom{8}{k}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{2^k}$, which by binomial theorem we see is $1-(1-\frac{1}{2})^8=1-(\frac{1}{2})^8$ (*remember that binomial theorem starts with the index $k=0$, hence the additional $1$ term outside of the parentheses*), the same answer as the first method.